# Elasticsearch - I am struggling to write a query on a field where 2 criteria need to be met

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am struggling to write a query on a field where 2 criteria need to be met for a dashboard in Kibana. My field name is test:keyword and I need the results to be where Test A **and** Test B have the result:keyword (another field) as PASS

```
{ "query": { 
 "match_phrase": { 
  "test.keyword": "EOL_Overall_test_result" } 
}
```

}

so I need another criteria and test.keyword:"EOL_flash_app_fw"

and these both need to have the result as:

result.keyword:"PASS"

```
 {
  "mte" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "EESWVer" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "acdID" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "board" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "create" : {
          "properties" : {
            "board" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "device" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
           }
        },
        "reason" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "result" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "test" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "timeStamp" : {
          "type" : "date"
            }
          }
        },
        "device" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "hostname" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "reason" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "result" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "test" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "timeStamp" : {
          "type" : "date"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**DOCUMENT SAMPLE**

```
    {
  "_index": "mte",
  "_type": "result",
  "_id": "fY1Amn4BTPepfjg1c5x5",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "timeStamp": "2022-01-27T14:37:01+08:00",
    "test": "EOL_Overall_test_result",
    "hostname": "eol-test-0",
    "acdID": "0x00A2F16A",
    "EESWVer": "0.3.0",
    "device": "",
    "result": "PASS",
    "reason": "0b001111111110011011111111",
    "board": "JENMUL90"
  },
  "fields": {
    "acdID.keyword": [
      "0x00A2F16A"
    ],
    "reason": [
      "0b001111111110011011111111"
    ],
    "device.keyword": [
      ""
    ],
    "test": [
      "EOL_Overall_test_result"
    ],
    "test.keyword": [
      "EOL_Overall_test_result"
    ],
    "result.keyword": [
      "PASS"
   ],
    "EESWVer.keyword": [
     "0.3.0"
    ],
    "board.keyword": [
      "JENMU90"
    ],
    "result": [
      "PASS"
    ],
    "timeStamp": [
     "2022-01-27T06:37:01.000Z"
    ],
    "hostname": [
      "eol-test-0"
    ],
    "reason.keyword": [
     "0b001111111110011011111111"
    ],
    "acdID": [
      "0x00A2F16A"
    ],
    "EESWVer": [
      "0.3.0"
    ],
    "hostname.keyword": [
      "eol-test-0"
    ],
    "device": [
      ""
    ],
    "board": [
      "JENMUL90"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show what you have so far?

Comment: {
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "test.keyword": "EOL_Overall_test_result"
    }
  }
}

so I need another criteria and test.keyword:"EOL_flash_app_fw"

and these both need to be result.keyword:"PASS"

Comment: Please update your question, as it's more legible

Comment: All done, I hope that makes sense. I know you can do OR but this is not what I want in this scenario

Comment: Can you share your mapping and also a sample document that should match?

Comment: please bear in mind, I am pretty much a beginner when it comes to all of it, I am just trying to get my head around JSON and things

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this query, as far as I understand, it should work the way you expect (not sure though as the `test` field seems to only contain one single value):

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "test.keyword": [
              "EOL_Overall_test_result",
              "EOL_flash_app_fw"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "result.keyword": "PASS"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you, well the term field can be PASS, FAIL, INFO do yes I only want PASS. it looks like it is working, I am just going to do some work to check the numbers, thanks for your help